# Why couldn't the idols smell their hands or touch their feet?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Hallel, [Tehillim 115:7-8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=428) it says:

אף להם ולא יריחון ידיהם ולא ימישון רגליהם

David is discussing the nations that built idols. These people believed that these idols were like human / gods. So, I would assume that when they designed these idols, they would give them powers similar to humans.

Yet, it seems that these people designed these idols in a way where they couldn't smell their hands or touch their feet. I don't get it. Why would these people build idols with such defects?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Their noses do not smell, and their feet do not run, but their noses run, and their feet smell.

Comment: @Fred - That couldn't be! Then they'd be upside down!

Answer (score 4):

David was referring to the Buddha. Buddha, in [some forms](http://www.iai-international.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/laughing_buddha_statue-1016x1024.jpg)<sup>1</sup> is ludicrously fat and cannot bring his hands close enough to his nose to smell them, and definitely couldn't touch his toes.

---

<sup>1</sup>**NOTE:** Contains an image considered by most contemporary *poskim* to be an idol.